# documentPicker:didPickDocumentAtURL: not invoke

Tags: ios8

I try to use storage provider extension in my app. So i have implemented UIdocumentPickerViewcontroller class to move file to other apps sandbox.I have presented document picker controller from host app and selected the destination to move the file in storage provider extension of other app.According to apple doc , when user clicks the move destination UIDocumentPickerDelegate method will invoke in host app to process the url returned by others apps.

But my case, delegate method `documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentAtURL:(NSURL *)url` not getting called. I am using ios8 beta4 and xcode6 beta 4. Is anyone have this issue? please help me to come out of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean and rebuild the code.

I experienced the same issue before, it was working on the emulator but not on the actually device. I have also implemented the documentPickerWasCancelled: method and it works on both cases.

I tried several changes, clean the project and rebuild and suddenly it also works on the device.

Hope it would work for you after cleaning and building the project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have same problem, i was presenting document by below code and i was trying to import image file in my case.

**This is code which was not working:**

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key"]
```

**Working code for import image in my case :**

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"com.apple.iwork.pages.pages", @"com.apple.iwork.numbers.numbers", @"com.apple.iwork.keynote.key", @"public.image"]
```

I have just added `@"public.image"` in my case and working like charm !!

You can add `UTIs` as per your requirements..